# Bootstrap modal not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason I am having trouble firing a bootstrap modal, below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link href="http://localhost/scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>Modal header</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button id="button">Fire</button>
        <script src="http://localhost/scripts/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function(){
             $("#button").click(function(){
                $('#modal').modal('show');
             });
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the `bootstrap` library **after** the `jQuery` library. Did you bother checking your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: if bootstrap itself providing a .js file why do we need jquery.js ?

Comment: @piperchester Bootstrap requires jQuery to be loaded/available in the browser, so it can modify (add stuff) to it. For example, anything in the "JavaScript" section of Bootstrap's website is in reference to the things you can use to initialize/config their components; they are an **extension** to the jQuery library. You can modify something that isn't available, therefore jQuery needs to be loaded **first**.

Comment: @Abhinay Bootstrap provides their library and only their library when you download/use it. If you want to use their JavaScript components (see their website), jQuery is **required** because they **extend jQuery**. jQuery needs to be available in order for Bootstrap to extend it, so it needs to be loaded **first**.